# SQL Server on Hyper-V on SQL Server 2012

Tags: hyper-v, sql-server-2012

I saw that this is the feature of AlwaysOn for SQL Server 2012. Can anyone explain the meaning of this? I mean can anyone give example or scenario? 
SQL Server on Hyper-V
SQL Server instances hosted on Hyper-V environment get the additional benefit of Live Migration which allows migration of virtual machines without any downtime. This allows administrators to do maintenance operations on the host without impacting applications.

And how is this different from SQL Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really want to answer with a link, but it's hard to beat Ozar when it comes to database stuff, so... well, [here's his take](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/11/sql-server-denali-database-mirroring-rocks/).

Better scalability, high availability functions and disaster recovery are the main highlights.  Try doing that with an older MSSQL cluster, and you'd usually end up with a splitting migraine and an almost working solution at the end of it.